# container not responsive when the window resizes - leaving white space on the right

Tags: html, css

The current website has 3 column block layout and I am trying to make it responsive. As the window gets small enough, the 3 columns turn into 2 columns, which is what I wanted. However, it leaves white space where the third column was used to be and I don't want the extra white space. So the white space should be hidden as the window gets smaller (this is what happens when the window is large enough for 3 columns. The white space on the right side gets hidden, until the 3 columns turns into 2).

Thank you. :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9V3W/3/)

html:

```
<body>

<div id="content">
<div class="grid3">
<article class="bucket" >
<a href="#">
<img src="images/baskerville1.jpg" alt=""/>
<div class = "img-overlay">
  <h3>Monogram</h3></div>
  </a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/Gastalt.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Gastalt Composition</h3>
  </div>
</a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/redThread.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>The Red Thread - A Visual Book</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/poster copy.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Typographic Hierarchy</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>

<article class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/Spaces.png" alt=""/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>Living in Two Spaces</h3>
  </div>
  </a>
</article>
```

css:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";

*{
    margin:0;
}

.bucket {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3.2%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.grid3 .bucket:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;
}

.grid3 .bucket{
    width: 31.2%;
}

.img-overlay h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    color: rgba(255,254,254,1.00);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling exact numbers in responsive layout (3col, 2col, etc.) should be done via percentages because it's heaps easier to control when and where breakpoints happen.
Here's a JSFiddle showcasing this: http://jsfiddle.net/sickdesigner/GLnfU/

Essentially, the key to the whole thing is having your .buckets set to percentages according to how many columns you want. This makes your article fill up their container in three columns (27.3+3+3 =  33.3*3 =  99.9%).

```
        .bucket{
            margin: 2% 3%;
            width: 27.3%; }
```

Also, for sanity's sake, I added a universal box-sizing. More on why box-sizing makes life easier here: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

However,
If you *really* want to let your content do what it want, when it feels like it, you could skip the whole matter of floating elements altogether. This is the more hippie-lovey-dovey version of this layout and while it looks sleek and sexy and makes coders, myself included, drool with code-lust, it also means leaving *a lot* to chance and the hope that your content won't break itself (think what would happen if the images were all different proportions to each other).

Here's another JSFiddle, this time with the hippie-drooly approach: http://jsfiddle.net/sickdesigner/zq8YC/1/

P.S.: the hippie-drooly approach also doesn't require media queries, which is kind of cool, actually.

Cheers!

Comment: The second one (definitely very hippy-drolly) is EXACTLY what I want. It really gives me a headache when the photos jumps to a different size as the window resizes. Haha! Thanks!

Comment: If you ever find yourself being forced to use the non-hippy-drooly approach, you can just add a transition to the image container. That way, when they do resize, it won't be jumpy, it'll be super smooth. As always, here be the Fiddle-diddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sickdesigner/GLnfU/1/

Comment: Sooooo pretty! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Happy to have been of some help!